# Arcanist - Error while doing arc diff

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Good day!

While Im doing sudo arc diff origin/develop and my git repositories are also updated (both local and on the github), it always have this error and still not  reflected on our Phabricator account.

Totally noob in using arc and phabricator.  I pasted here the error message since I also did --trace.

Thank you.  And anyone can suggest a good blog/tutorial about arcanist and phabricator for beginners?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to update an existing diff that has already been marked as closed.  if you want to update that old diff, you will need to re-open it or use `arc diff origin/develop --create`